# Java Error: class file for com.google.common.base.Predicate not found

Tags: java

When trying to execute this code:

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections(
    new ConfigurationBuilder().setScanners(
        new SubTypesScanner(false),
        new ResourcesScanner())
    .setUrls(ClasspathHelper.forClassLoader(
        classLoadersList.toArray(new ClassLoader[0])))
    .filterInputsBy(new FilterBuilder()
        .include(FilterBuilder.prefix(packageName))));
```

It turns out the error:

> **class file** for `com.google.common.base.Predicate` **not found**.

How to fix it?

Comment: It doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: I faced same issue for Predicate & Collect, then added below and it worked:

    <dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
  <artifactId>guava-base</artifactId>
  <version>r03</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
  <artifactId>guava-collections</artifactId>
  <version>r03</version>
 </dependency>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guava library must be added to your class path. Since Guava is not a plug-in, you have to add it manually. You can follow the steps below to add it to your class path:

1. Right click on your project
2. Build path
3. Configure build path
4. Libraries
5. Add external jars
6. Find the JAR file for Guava
7. OK / OPEN